# Gnosis error fix - $

Tags: gnosis-safe, error, bsc

Long story short - received payment long ago from a customer, but it was caught up in a gnosis safe error so we couldn't pull the BNB into our wallet. It is sitting here, currently worth $105k.

0x1D8769b57aaf4E3C0A64fC2f035F1EfA134FE24c

We need help fixing the error and getting the funds out. I will stay anonymous until we decide on who will help us, but we are a reputable web3 company. We are hoping to hire someone with the skill set to fix this. Tx hash is here

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x282779829d04e2c827f191583421a73537990220f6da4685d0312281a26e3e36

Will pay 8.0 BNB ($3,800 as of today's value) upon successful completion of transaction.

What pay requires from you before/upon hire.

1. High level explanation of how you will fix it
2. Your background
3. A video call with myself and 2-3 of the founders so we can execute it

Please send me a message on why you'd be a good fit for the task, and I will reach out via email/telegram if interested. Please leave a method to contact you.

We did have someone on board helping us previously and outlined specific steps, so that may even help you, but I've lost contact with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the transaction unstuck? `GS020` means that there was a problem with validating signatures for that transaction. You probably tried to execute the transaction again from Safe wallet UI?

Happy to see it got resolved anyway.